# Do you create a cname for domain.com/blog or only for blog.domain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

server#1 hosts domain.com content.

If I want to map a different IP on another server to domain.com/blog would I use a CNAME record for this?

Or is a cname only for blog.domain.com ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CNAME (and anything related to domain names) only covers the part up to the first slash.

In order to host domain.com/blog on a different IP, you'll need to do some sort of proxying on the web server that handles domain.com.  It'll be quite a bit easier to use blog.domain.com instead, if that's feasible.